# When to implement iNotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

From my understanding, it appears that `INotifyPropertyChanged` is very useful when working with UI elements that are related to one object source. I'm just curious as to why some classes in the .net framework which may in some way be used with the UI do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? For example `SerialPort` class.

Is there a recommended guideline on the use of `INotifyPropertyChanged`? or have I totally misunderstood the concept of the interface?

This question was brought about after trying to link several custom user controls to the `SerialPort` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You understood the interface correctly.

But thinking `SerialPort` class is somehow related to UI is the bad thing. This class is supposed to allow access to this one resource. Nothing more, nothing less. If you want to somehow display information related to `SerialPort`, you should create your own business class, that will use `SerialPort` and expose needed information through properties and `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Ah, its starting to make sense now. Would there be a case where a class which is also the data source make use of the INotifyPropertyChanged directly without having to create a business class?

Answer (score 2):

Generally INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented on class having business logic of application developed for WPF or Silverlight.

If SerialPort class is used by other applications like WCF or Winform 2.0, INotifyPropertyChanged will be of little or no use.

Anyway its an interface that is understood by WPF framework engine.
And You can create a business class which can implement INotifyPropertyChanged and internally hold SerialPort class.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I don't come from a computer science/development background, and so terminology such as 'business logic', 'factories', 'builders' etc. is very alien to me. What is the general topic that these terms fall under so I can read up on?

Comment: When one drive car, he/she has to acquaint with the terms like 'brake', 'clutch', 'accelerator', 'gears' etc. You can consider above terminologies in softwares like aforementioned for cars. Business logic in vague term is converting your requirements in software code. Try to explore 'Software Engineering' by Roger Pressman, read on software design and architectures.

Answer (score 1):

INotifyPropertyChanged is to allow objects to communicate to their bindings, so in that sense your understanding is correct.

You can [wrap](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/netfxbcl/thread/980548bf-676c-4e22-a6c6-ab52cb41171d) the SerialPort to provide this.

I'm not sure why SerialPort doesn't implement this interface, so in that sense I can't answer that part of the question.